# Access is denied when Remove-Service even though the SDDL contains account SID

Tags: windows-services, powershell-core, sddl

`Remove-Service` fails with Access is denied (PermissionDenied) even though the SID of the account that the PowerShell script runs under was added to the SDDL of the service when it was created:

```
$sddl = "D:(A;;0xF01FF;;;S-1-1-11-1111111111-222222222-333333333-444444)(...original SDDL...)"
New-Service -SecurityDescriptorSddl $sddl ...
```

`S-1-1-11-1111111111-222222222-333333333-444444` is the SID of the account that the PowerShell `Remove-Service` runs under.

I expected that the account is allowed to delete the service when SDDL contains DACL with `SERVICE_ALL_ACCESS` (`0xF01FF`) as `SERVICE_ALL_ACCESS` includes `STANDARD_RIGHTS_REQUIRED` that contains `DELETE`.